# Given latitude and longitude on a spherical Earth, what North-South or East-West variation equals $1$km?

Tags: geometry

> Consider the earth a perfect sphere. Given a latitude and a longitude, what variation on any perpendicular direction (you either move N$\leftrightarrow$S or W$\leftrightarrow$E) equals to 1KM? (or 3200 foot)

PS: this is not homework. I'm working with geo-spatial data.

Comment: 1 km is not 3200 feet.

Comment: its close enough....

Answer (score 1):

For a spherical earth, one minutee of latitude is one nautical mile, about $6076$ feet.  One minute of longitude is that much at the equator.  At higher latitudes, the distance is multiplied by the cosine of the latitude.

You can derive it if you have the diameter of the earth you are using.  Multiply by $2 \pi$ for the circumference and divide by $360^\circ$ and $60$ minutes per degree

Answer (score 0):

Quarter circumference of Earth subtends $90^{\circ} $ or $ (90\times 60 ) $  minutes of arc, and it measures $ \approx 10,020 $ km.

Calculates to $\approx 0.54$ minutes of arc per km .. either along any meridian/longitude NS or along equator EW latitude.

For higher latitudes multiply this angle by $ \sec \phi $ where $\phi$ is absolute value of latitude.